# .net webhandler force download dialog to client c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, download

I am having a bit of a problem with a web applcation I am developing in .net with C#. I am using a WebHandler that responds to an ajax call from the client, and executes a function that creates a file. What I want is to display  download dialog at the end of the file creation process, however the Response class does not exist in the context of the function called by the handler. How to force the application to show the download dialog to the user after file creation? I was thinking about uilding a callback function to the ajax call, and when the execution of the first ajax call returns do another ajax call to a different WebHandler that will force the download dialog. Is this the most efficient way to do this? Is this even correct? What other more orthodox ways can I use to achive what I want? Thank you for yor help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider taking AJAX about of the solution and just redirecting or setting the window.location to the WebHandler url, which will trigger the file download dialog on the browser. Once the user accepts the download, the browser will remain on the page.

Maybe there are more details as to why Ajax is needed.  If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your tip: "just redirecting or setting the window.location to the WebHandler url, which will trigger the file download dialog on the browser". It works

Answer (score 0):

On the success operation of your ajax call once the file has been created by the handler just navigate to the file... eihter using C# or JavaScript